# pythonVSCode, venv and pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

A newbie question. I am trying to get pythonVSCode working with a venv virtual environment for Python 3.6 on a Mac.

Following [the documentation](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Python-Path-and-Version#option-2-activate-the-virtual-environment-from-your-terminalcommand-window-and-then-launch-vs-code), I activated the virtual environment and launched VSCode from the terminal.

When VSCode suggested installing pylint, I tried using the pythonVSCode's "Install" button that came with the suggestion, but that threw an error in VSCode's terminal:

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install pylint
$ /usr/bin/python -m pip install pylint
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

I then installed pylint via the system (not VSCode's) terminal and within the virtual environment:

```
(venv) $ pip install pylint
```

... and re-launched VSCode from the terminal.

VSCode still suggests installing pylint.

I suspect this has something to do with paths. I expected launching VSCode from within the virtual environment will load that environment's interpreter including pylint in VSCode, but it seems not to be the case.

Comment: You might find using option 1 in the docs easier and safer and just setting the interpreter path explicitly for your workspace. Also are you sure you're actually running python3 in the first place? All of these look like invocations of the system python which is a python 2.

Comment: Did you instead try: `python3 -m pip install pylint`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem as of 07/2018.

Solution:
activate your virtualenv:

```
source yourenv/bin/activate
```

in the terminal with the active virtualenv, do the following:

Install pylint in your virtualenv:

```
 (yourenv) user@machine/your/env/folder$ pip install pylint
```

Open VSCODE from the terminal, inside your virtualenv, using the "code" command. Let open only the new VSCode instance.

```
(yourenv) user@machine/your/env/folder$ code
```

Have fun coding using pylint.

Comment: I did exactly what you said here, but it did not work.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

You are right, it's about paths. You should have something like this in your
*settings.json* file:

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "your_project_path/your_venv/Scripts/python",
  "python.linting.pylintPath": "your_project_path/your_venv/Scripts/pylint"
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Solved the same problem on ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Seems like you need to install pip for python. Found [this](https://github.com/k4m4/kickthemout/issues/107) thread for mac:

```
sudo port install py27-pip
```

Then update your PATH to include py27-pip bin directory (you can add this in ~/.bash_profile 
  "PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH"

Comment: This has nothing to do with the virtualenv question